# Unable to run multiple OSRM Docker instances by using multiple port

Tags: docker, osrm

i am trying to create OSRM Docker for 2 country 
so first instanaces I created this like

```
sudo docker run -t -i  -p 192.168.0.2:5000:5000 -v $(pwd):/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/great-latest.osm.pbf
```

now i am trying to start the 2nd instances from a different Directory like this

```
sudo docker run -t -i -p 192.168.0.2:6000:6000  -v $(pwd):/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/-latest.osm.pbf
```

but the 2nd one is creating like bellow, it seems to me 2nd one is also referencing to port 5000, I can see port 6000 is open, but it does not take any connection.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                    NAMES
e5a1a2b3e040        osrm/osrm-backend                "osrm-routed --algor…"   14 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds           5000/tcp, 192.168.0.2:6000->6000/tcp   tender_elbakyan


c9ac75bdcea9        osrm/osrm-backend                "osrm-routed --algor…"   8 days ago          Up 8 days               192.168.0.2:5000->5000/tcp             awesome_murdock
```

netstat out put

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.2:6000      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN


telnet  192.168.0.2 6000
```

i am sure in past it worked.. 
any help will be really appreciate

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last port number in the `docker run -p` option is the port number *inside the container* that the server is listening on.  This is usually fixed per image, and you probably want it to be 5000 in both cases

```
sudo docker run -p 192.168.0.2:5000:5000 ...
sudo docker run -p 192.168.0.2:6000:5000 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second invocation should be:

```
sudo docker run -t -i -p 192.168.0.2:6000:5000  -v $(pwd):/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/-latest.osm.pbf
```

The service inside the container is still listening on port 5000, and you are mapping the host port 6000 to container port 6000, which is not being listened on on the container side.